# HTAccess for Laravel 4 sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, subdomain

Getting really frustrated trying to configure the whole redirecting business. I have laravel as a sub directory to the main root. So instead of doing this:

```
Route::get('/game/quiz/', 'HomeController@showQuiz');
Route::get('/game/quiz/home', 'HomeController@showQuiz');
Route::get('/game/quiz/boho', 'HomeController@showBoho');
Route::get('/game/quiz/chic', 'HomeController@showChic');
Route::get('/game/quiz/elegant', 'HomeController@showElegant');
Route::get('/game/quiz/glamour', 'HomeController@showGlamour');
Route::get('/game/quiz/quirky', 'HomeController@showQuirky');
Route::post('/game/quiz/submitQuiz', 'QuizController@submitQuiz');
```

^^ Causes 404's for all public assets

I ideally want this:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showQuiz');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@showQuiz');
Route::get('boho', 'HomeController@showBoho');
Route::get('chic', 'HomeController@showChic');
Route::get('elegant', 'HomeController@showElegant');
Route::get('glamour', 'HomeController@showGlamour');
Route::get('quirky', 'HomeController@showQuirky');
Route::post('submitQuiz', 'QuizController@submitQuiz');
```

This is my main app htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Points to public folder which is fine.

now public folder htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

$_SERVER when i dd();

```
["REQUEST_URI"] "/game/quiz/"
["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"] "/home/sites/mywebsite.co.uk/public_html/"
["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] "/home/sites/mywebsite.co.uk/public_html/game/quiz/public/index.php"
["SCRIPT_URI"] "http://mywebsite.co.uk/game/quiz/"
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths are configured in file /bootstrap/paths.php

add /game/quiz to all paths defined in this file. If configured correctly with absolute path or path relative to folder bootstrap then you will get your problem solved.

Comment: I don't have this file in L5.1, how can I do this?